# Rspec error, can't figure it out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

So I am testing public profiles and I am getting the following error

```
1) Visiting profiles not signed in shows profile
 Failure/Error: expect( page ).to have_content(@post.title)
   expected to find text "Post title" in "Bloccit About Sign In or Sign Up Posts 
   Comments"
 # ./spec/features/profiles_spec.rb:22:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is my profile_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

 describe "Visiting profiles" do 

  include TestFactories

  before do 
    @user = authenticated_user
    @post = associated_post(user: @user)
    @comment = Comment.new(user: @user, body: "A Comment")
    allow(@comment).to receive(:send_favorite_emails)
    @comment.save 
  end

  describe "not signed in" do 

    it "shows profile" do 
    visit user_path(@user)
    expect(current_path).to eq(user_path(@user))

    expect( page ).to have_content(@user.name)
    expect( page ).to have_content(@post.title)
    expect( page ).to have_content(@comment.body)
  end

 end
end
```

I am not sure what else could be wrong.

It seems like the view is looking at the main page and not to the user profile.

This is the user_controller show

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @posts = @user.posts
  @comments = @user.comments
end
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML on your show page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mckay74 -- The issue is a slight one.

In ERB, `<% some ruby %>` executes Ruby. `<%= some ruby %>` executes that ruby AND prints it to the page. You used the former, so while your Ruby is executing, it's not showing up in the final HTML. Add those `=`s, (to the lines that should actually print) and your test should pass.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize my typo